# JavaScript | appendChild to all classes

Tags: javascript

I have problem with append Child to whole classes in my document which the name of class is "onbackorder". Here is my code:

```
<script>
    var first = document.createElement("p");
    var text = document.createTextNode("On backorder");
    first.appendChild(text);

    var isRequestQuote = document.getElementsByClassName('onbackorder');
    if (isRequestQuote.length > 0) {
        document.querySelector(".onbackorder").appendChild(first);
    }
</script>
```

For this moment function put selector randomly. How can I get same selector in whole document where class is "onbackorder".

Thank you

Comment: You have an HTML collection with `isRequestQuote`. Iterate over that an create a new text element _in the loop_ and append that to the element in the current iteration of the loop. There's no need for that `querySelector`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 points:

1. `document.querySelector(".onbackorder")` is just return first item. So you need to use `document.querySelectorAll('.onbackorder')`.

> The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within
> the document that matches the specified selector, or group of
> selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

2. `var first = document.createElement("p");` you have to create multiple reference variable to append to each `onbackorder` item. Because you cannot create only one and append to multiple items.

So I modified your code and make it works. You can check it at below:

```js
var first = document.createElement("p");
var text = document.createTextNode("On backorder");
first.appendChild(text);

const allBackOrders = document.querySelectorAll('.onbackorder');
allBackOrders.forEach((item) => {
  var newItem = first.cloneNode(true);
  item.appendChild(newItem);
});
```

```html
<div class="onbackorder"></div>
<div class="onbackorder"></div>
<div class="onbackorder"></div>
```

Comment: Your code is still using both `getElementsByClasses` and `querySelectorAll` to target the same elements. Is that necessary?

Comment: Instead of creating the same DOM over and over again, creating it once (outside the loop) and using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode with an argument of `true` might save some work.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for your optimized suggestion. I updated it. Thanks :))

Comment: @Ryuno-Ki Wow, I don't know that before. I've learned a new thing today and updated it. Thanks.

Comment: Yay! Happy to help :-)